# composer update laravel 5.5 to laravel 5.6 gets hangs with updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Tags: php, laravel

I am upgrading my laravel project to 5.6. current version is 5.5.44. my composer file is as below. when i run composer update, it does nothing but showing Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) in the terminal for hours. what would be the issue for this?

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.7",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.33",
        "maximebf/debugbar": "~1.15.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "artem-schander/l5-modular": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "hesto/multi-auth": "^1.0",
        "laravel/cashier": "~7.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/twilio": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "2.0.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.3",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0",
        "psr/container": "^1.0",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/inflector": "^1.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.1.5",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
    },



$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.5.44
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Comment: did you follow this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0 ?

Comment: try with ```composer update -vvv``` to see the current progress and some detail report of why it fails

Comment: yes. I do follow.

Comment: when i use composer update -vvv it hangs here

Reading /Users/MACuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-error-response.json from cache
Resolving dependencies through SAT

Answer (score 1):

try removing the abandoned package:

```
"phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
```

Comment: it hangs here 

    Reading /Users/MACuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-guzzle$plugin-error-response.json from cache 

    Resolving dependencies through SAT